# Use PHP variable in href inside of html inside of php?

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to make a cart for my website (nothing too special, uni project).

Currently I have

```
$product_id = $row["ID"];
$product_name  = $row['name'];
$product_price = $row['price'];
$product_image = $row['img'];
$imgurl = ".\img\\".$product_image;

if ($i % 3 == 0) { // if $i is divisible by our target number (in this case "3")
    $dyn_table .= '<tr><td align="center" valign="middle" width="350">'. "<img src=$imgurl width='100' hieght='100'> <br />" . $product_name . '<br /> &pound'.$product_price . '<br /><a href="./cart.php?product="$product_id"&action=add" />Add to Card</a></td>';
} else {
    $dyn_table .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" width="350">'. "<img src=$imgurl width='100' hieght='100'> <br />" . $product_name . '<br /> &pound'.$product_price . '<a href="./cart.php?product=$product_id&action=add" />Add to Card</a></td>';
```

I need to have the product ID inserted in href where I have $product_id

```
<a href="./cart.php?product=$product_id&action=add" />Add to Card</a>
```

Currenly, it loads the links as domain.com/cart.php?product=$product_id&action=add

Comment: Single-quoted strings don't expand variables: `'<br /><a href="./cart.php?product="' . $product_id . '"&action=add" /> ...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use variable name between quotes
provided if it is a single quoted you have to put {} around variable 
else if it is a double quotes you can directly use the varibale

```
if ($i % 3 == 0) {
$dyn_table .= "<tr><td align='center' valign='middle' width='350'>". "<img src=$imgurl width='100' hieght='100'> <br />" . $product_name . "<br /> &pound".$product_price . "<br />
<a href='./cart.php?product={$product_id}&action=add' />Add to Card</a></td>";
} else {
$dyn_table .= "<td align='center' valign='middle' width='350'>". "<img src=$imgurl width='100' hieght='100'> <br />" . $product_name . "<br /> &pound".$product_price . "<a href='./cart.php?product={$product_id}&action=add' />Add to Card</a></td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable has to be extracted from the string, in PHP, so:

```
<a href="./cart.php?product='.$product_id.'&action=add" />Add to Card</a>
```

Like you did for your other variables.

Comment: You wouldn't use `echo`, or PHP tags, in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
$dyn_table .= '<tr><td align="center" valign="middle" width="350">'."<img src=$imgurl width='100' hieght='100'><br />" . $product_name.'<br /> &pound'.$product_price .'<br /><a href="./cart.php?product=" .$product_id. "&action=add." />Add to Card</a></td>';
```

Comment: Doing it like this makes the URL load as /cart.php?product=

Comment: I suspect that variable does not contain the right data. edit: try it again, I didn't clean up some extra quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem was that you didn't jump out of single quotes properly to add `$product_id` in, however there's another instrumental problem in your code.

You should either use all `''` single quotes or all `""` double quotes, not a combination of both. It makes it hard to read and is unnecessary regardless.

Therefore, it should be either

```
$dyn_table .= '<tr><td align="center" valign="middle" width="350"><img src="' . $imgurl . '" width="100" hieght="100"> <br />' . $product_name . '<br /> &pound;' . $product_price . '<br /><a href="./cart.php?product=' . $product_id . '&action=add" />Add to Card</a></td>';
```

or

```
$dyn_table .= "<tr><td align=\"center\" valign=\"middle\" width=\"350\"><img src=\"$imgurl\" width=\"100\" hieght=\"100\"> <br />$product_name<br /> &pound;$product_price<br /><a href=\"./cart.php?product=$product_id&action=add\" />Add to Card</a></td>";
```

In this case, I'd probably use single quotes so I don't have to escape all the double quotes in the HTML, or perhaps even a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), but I won't get into those for now.

Your code for single quotes would be

```
if ($i % 3 == 0) { // if $i is divisible by our target number (in this case "3")
    $dyn_table .= '<tr><td align="center" valign="middle" width="350"><img src="' . $imgurl . '" width="100" height="100"> <br />' . $product_name . '<br /> &pound;' . $product_price . '<br /><a href="./cart.php?product=' . $product_id . '&action=add" />Add to Card</a></td>';
} else {
    $dyn_table .= '<td align="center" valign="middle" width="350"><img src="' . $imgurl . '" width="100" hieght="100"> <br />' . $product_name . '<br /> &pound;' . $product_price . '<a href="./cart.php?product=' . $product_id . '&action=add" />Add to Card</a></td>';
```

I'd suggest you look up [heredocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) though, you may find those easier.